# Get sub-menu items page titles in PHP and Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've got a PHP code block that will assign a heading a different style depending on the main page title. However, my site has multiple sub-menu items for each main page as well. The code currently works in assigning new styles to the main navigation pages but isn't assigning the colour profiles to the sub-page style elements. How can I expand my solution to accommodate any new sub-pages (i.e. a wordpress/php function that gets the sub-pages of the main navigation item).

Here's my code:

```
if(get_the_title($ID) === "Services") {
     echo '<style type="text/css">
                .header-page h1 {
                        background-color: #9B87A9;
                    }

                    .header-page h2 {
                        background-color: #9B87A9;
                    }
                </style>';
}
else if(get_the_title($ID) === "About") {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
                .header-page h1 {
                        background-color: #dea949;
                    }

                    .header-page h2 {
                        background-color: #dea949;
                    }
                </style>';
}
```

So I'm looking for something similar to `get_the_title($ID)` to accommodate any of Services sub-menu items or About. I want a more automated solution rather than hard code each sub-page title into my `if` statement.

Comment: @Prava-MindfireSolutions Don't try to "fix" source code in a question. If the source code is part of the problem, provide an answer that shows the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the css to the page try adding the class to the element.